# Dynamic Watermark in PHP

Tags: php, dynamic, watermark

I'm using this script to create a watermark on one of client's websites the problem is that one watermark is suitable for one image and unsuitable for another.

Portrait

[image: This is for Portrait photos]

Landscape
[image: This is for landscape photos]

Here is the script:

```
<?php 
// this script creates a watermarked image from an image file - can be a .jpg .gif or .png file 
// where watermark.gif is a mostly transparent gif image with the watermark - goes in the same directory asthis script 
// where this script is named watermark.php 
// call this script with an image tag 
// <img src="watermark.php?path=imagepath"> where path is a relative path such as subdirectory/image.jpg 

$imagesource = $_GET['path']; 

$filetype = substr($imagesource,strlen($imagesource)-4,4); 

$filetype = strtolower($filetype); 

if($filetype == ".gif") $image = @imagecreatefromgif($imagesource); 

if($filetype == ".jpg") $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($imagesource); 

if($filetype == ".png") $image = @imagecreatefrompng($imagesource);    


if (!$image) die(); 

//This bit is the dynamic bit
if(imagesx($image) <=1100){

$watermark = @imagecreatefromgif('watermark_port.gif');

}elseif(imagesx($image) <=1600 && $imagewidth >1100){

$watermark = @imagecreatefromgif('watermark_lans.gif'); 

}elseif(imagesx($image) >1600){

$watermark = @imagecreatefromgif('watermark_lans.gif'); 

};
//End of dynamic code

$imagewidth = imagesx($image); 

$imageheight = imagesy($image); 


$watermarkwidth = imagesx($watermark); 

$watermarkheight = imagesy($watermark); 



$startwidth = (($imagewidth - $watermarkwidth)/2); 

$startheight = (($imageheight - $watermarkheight)/2); 

imagecopy($image, $watermark, $startwidth, $startheight, 0, 0, $watermarkwidth,
$watermarkheight); 

imagejpeg($image); 

imagedestroy($image); 

imagedestroy($watermark); 

?>
```

However the dynamic watermark doesn't work. What i want is if the image is under 1100px wide then it uses the portrait version and if it is over that to use the landscape version instead.

Any idea would be greatly apprieciated.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your "dynamic part" is doing is basically summed up as:

```
if something
    do A
else if something
    do B
else
    do B
```

The middle one is completely redundant.

What you need is just:

```
$watermark =
  imagecreatefromgif("watermark_".(imagesx($image) <= 1100 ? "port" : "lans").".gif");
```